# How can i apply lens effect to my UIImage?

Tags: iphone, image-processing, uiimage

How can i apply lens effect to my UIImage like it shown here http://processing.org/learning/topics/lens.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) framework to do that.

If you choose to use it, here is how you can easily apply a lens effect:

```
- (void)aFunction
{
    const CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    // Init and position your image
    CCSprite *img = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"images.png"];
    img.position = ccp(size.width/2.f, size.height/2.f);
    [self addChild:img];

    // Create action and start it
    id lens = [CCLens3D actionWithPosition:ccp(size.width/2.f, size.height/2.f)
                                    radius:240.f
                                      grid:ccg(15.f,10.f)
                                  duration:0.f];
    [img runAction:lens];
}
```

Your project is probably a UIKit project so you don't want to restart your project from scratch. So, in the cocos2d-ios Xcode project there are a lot of examples of what you can do.

And there is an exemple which is called AttachTest and it show you how implement an EAGLView (which is a subclass of UIView) in an UIKit project.

Comment: Thank you but i want make this effect from scratch. Can you provide me some code or an algorithm?

Comment: @dpart You should take a look on how Cocos2D do it. Its an OpenGL framework based, I think you could take some code from it for you...