# Zooming lens functionality over UIImage

Tags: iphone

I am working on an application that has an image and I want a lens (circular shape) that I can move over the image and the area comes under the circular lens will zoom.

Please provide some idea. This functionality is implemented in the app named PimpleEraser in AppStore.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6126515/840973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.craftymind.com/2009/02/10/creating-the-loupe-or-magnifying-glass-effect-on-the-iphone/) is a great tutorial on exactly what you want, a sort of magnifying glass.

Comment: @user1101920 No problem :) if this answer was the best answer, at the left of my answer there should be a number (it is 0 right now) with an arrow above and below it. To the left of that there should be a checkmark. That is used to select the best answer. Cheers

Comment: this is what exactly I want...

Comment: @user1101920 then press the green check mark under the number to the left of my answer ^_^ here is an example, just look at the first answer on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535916/how-can-i-test-for-null-and-not-null-at-the-same-time-in-sql