# How can I test for null and not null at the same time in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this sql:

```
select * from employees
where
lastname like '%smith%' and firstname like '%bob%' and middle like '%%'
```

The problem is the values of the name, particularly the middle name, can be null.  So the statement above will find:

```
  smith, bob mike
```

but will not find

```
  smith, bob
```

because Bob's middle name is null (he has no middle name.)

I have this which works but I thought there was a better way and wanted input:

```
    select * from employees
    where
    lastname like '%smith%' 
    and firstname like '%bob%' 
    and (middle like '%%' or middle is null)
```

edit:

middle is not always blank.  Sometimes it will have a value so I have to keep the test for middle name in.  It could be populated or null.

Thanks.  I am using Oracle 11g if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nvl:

```
select * from employees
where
lastname like '%smith%' and firstname like '%bob%' and nvl(middle,'') like '%%'
```

But this is just the same as not checking the middle name at all as like '%%' will match anything other than null.

Comment: Pretty much what ruakh said, the middle like '%%' or middle is null will always return true so there is no need to include it.

Comment: middle will not always be %% it can have a value.

Comment: I think this is the same as I have but much prettier.

Comment: That won't work: in Oracle, `''` is null (there's no concept of an empty string in Oracle, even as an intermediate value; anything that seems like it should be an empty string is actually null), so `NVL(middle, '') LIKE '%%'` means `NVL(middle, NULL) LIKE '%%'` means `middle LIKE '%%'`, and will only be true when `middle` is non-null.

Comment: It seems to be working so far.  Really, I don't know why.  It is picking up null and non-null.  nvl(middle,'') means replace the null with ''.  I put 'n/a'.

Comment: @johnny: Yes, `NVL(middle, 'n/a')` would work. I'm not saying that `NVL` never does anything, I'm saying that `NVL(middle, '')` *specifically* (with an empty string) is equivalent to plain `middle`.

Answer (score 5):

But

```
middle like '%%' or middle is null
```

is always true: either `middle` is null, in which case `middle is null` is true, or it contains one or more characters, in which case `middle like '%%'` is true. So you can just write:

```
select * from employees
where
lastname like '%smith%' and firstname like '%bob%'
```

Comment: but sometimes they will have the middle name such as middle like %albert% so I have to test for all of them.

Comment: @johnny: Are you saying that you'd want the equivalent of `middle LIKE '%albert%' OR middle IS NULL`? That is, even if the query specifies `middle LIKE '%albert%'`, you'd want to skip that check when `middle IS NULL`?

Comment: I'm saying middle can have a value or be null.  It will always have one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just drop the "middle" constraint from the query?
It seems like you don not really mind what it's value will be, so why not just:

```
select * from employees
where
lastname like '%smith%' and firstname like '%bob%'
```

Comment: No, I care what the value of middle is.  I only put %% because that doesn't pick up null and sometimes middle will not be null and I need to test that as well.